# Python/scipy - Optimizing function with constraint greater but NOT equal to zero

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, constraints, inequality

I'm developping a code that find the optimized condition for two independent variables h and t that define the function W(h,t). I want to minimize this function because that is the weight function. The task is:

- h and t are geometric features and consequently must not be zero or negative. h > 0 and t > 0

So that is an optimization problem with an inequality constraint h > 0 and t > 0. All the methods that I found don't work with this type of inequality. Can someone please help me with how can I do it with Scipy, or even a method that consider this type of inequality?
Grateful

I just searched optimization methods in scipy documentation but nothing about minimazing function with constraint >0.

Comment: Such strict inequality constraints typically have no solution.  Consider this simple example: minimize f(x) = x with the constraint x > 0. Mathematically, there is no solution (if there was proposed solution x* > 0, then x*/2 would be a better solution).  With finite precision floating point, you would have to pick the smallest representable positive floating point value--but is that really a useful result?

Comment: Are the variables continuous or integral? What is the definition of W? Is W linear? We cannot offer more specific advice unless there is more specific information in the question.

Comment: In an optimizer that doesn't directly support exclusive inequalities this can often be hacked in with an auxiliary constraint, but you haven't even specified which optimizer you're using.